# Detecting visual studio edition in IDE

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to detect which version of Visual studio is running my project when it is running through IDE , By using that I want to find out the path of visual studio in MyDocuments like:
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2012

Is there any C# method that can help me using VS2012?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? What's the ultimate goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Visual Studio Edition with the following code:

```
  public static class EnvInfo
  {
      public static string GetEdition()
      {
        EnvDTE.DTE dte =(EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
        return dte.Edition;
      }
  }
```

Note:

Be sure to include `EnvDTE.dll` before running this code.

Comment: Dear Bhushan Thanks a lot for your useful reply, when I run the above code, most of the time I get run time error: "Call was rejected with the callee ( exception from HRResult :.... ) , is there any other thing that I have to care?

Comment: @Albert That is because you are trying to access the information of the instance you are running...

Comment: I have prepared a control that other developers who want to use it will have the same problem, I need this only when running project from IDE.please advice.

Comment: @Albert I actually don't know how to solve it, but this code makes interaction with the COM libraries, so if the user is running the VS2010 without administarator previleges can get this error.So running VS in administrator mode can solve this problem IMO..:)

Answer (score 0):

Not related to Visual Studio, but here is the code to detect the directory where the executable is located:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

You can then check if the path contains the string "Visual Studio" and act accordingly.